# Class Has Changed into Component class in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, components

I have implemented a class that extends System.Timers.Timer object. When I then save the class, VS changes it into component class. This is quite disturbing because opening that class makes VS open some Component Designer show up instead of the source code.

Is there a way to prevent VS2008 to change my class into a component???

Regards, Danijel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Timers.Timer inherits from Component. Therefore, as long as your class inhertis from System.Timers.Timer, it will also be a component.

You can, however, choose to use the text editor instead of the graphical component editor as default action in the VS 2008.